# Failing to install a babygate to a stone wall

Tags: walls, doors, drill

I need to fit a baby gate to the top of some stairs. The manual of the gate we bought says it is meant to be screwed on a wooden wall. Our wall is stone, so we first tried drilling holes and using screw anchors. After a few days the gate is starting to come off the wall with the anchors. We have stopped using it until it's fixed. [image]
[image]
It seems like the force applied perpendicularly to the wall when opening/locking is too much for the anchors. What can we try?

Comment: Stone seems more likely to be a translation issue than what you have for a wall, from the pictures. If you have a stone wall and the anchors you used are not holding, you used the wrong anchors. If you have a sheetrock/plaster/gypsum-board wall the anchors pulling out is not surprising.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "stucco" instead of "stone"? The anchors that came with the gate are probably only good for wood. If you have drywall (easy to drill into), you should get something like heavy-duty toggle-bolts; if you have stucco or stone (very hard to drill into) you will need special anchors/systems for those. A local hardware store should be able to help you figure out how to anchor your gate.

Comment: What is the other side? Perhaps it is a stair post, which may hold the gate better.

Answer (score 5):

IMO there is no dry-wall fastener that's gonna hold a baby gate.  Not because of the weight, but because it's a dynamic load.  It's moved, pulled on, etc... all the time.

Since this is a "temporary" thing, it doesn't have to be beautiful.  I would get a piece of 1" pine boarding, and cut 2 pieces long enough to bridge between two existing studs behind the drywall (there are tons of methods of locating those studs).  Screw it to the studs, screw the gate to the new wood.  Very secure for the year or two that you need it.   If the gate screws loosen up over time, just shift the gate a 1/2" or so and drill new holes.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly using wrong anchors for stone or specially if it is dry wall.

On the photo it looks like dry wall (gypsum plates)

For stone (brick) wall you need special anchors for that, and long enough so they do not come out.

For dry wall you need special anchors made for that as well.

Usually this type dry wall anchor would be enough for the gate anchors, very easy to use, just do not drill big hole, they are made to self drill.

[image: dry wall anchor]

If you need much stronger anchor, this type does that.

[image]

From right to left:

Right one is good for brick wall not for dry wall

The second one is also ok for brick wall, not good enough for dry wall

The third is specially made for dry wall.

The 4th is for dry wall and extra strong.

The 5th is for dry wall but the size choice is dry wall thickness dependent.

[image: anchors]